# Swift - pushViewController programmatically without ViewController

Tags: swift, swift4

I'd like to add a countdown to my app that reboots the app in two minutes. I dont want to restart the app physically. I only want to open the ViewController. 
The problem is that this function should be called from every page/ViewController.

So I created a Util/Helper class/Singleton which should handle this. But I cannot call the pushViewController method because it is no ViewController class. So I have no navigationController and I think it is not possible to pass this navigationController. 
How could I handle it?

Passing the navigationController to the Manager called an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

```
@objc func decrementCounter(vc: UINavigationController) {
        if(counter == 0) {
            let viewController = ViewController()
            vc.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        } else {
            counter -= 1
        }
        print("Counter: \(counter)")
    }
```

Comment: where is your timer code?

Comment: in my Helper/Singleton class. Not inside my viewcontroller because I want to reduce the redundant code.

Comment: @TorbenG make a function where you assign a fresh root navigation controller to the pointing to your start screen view controller , you can create a navigation controller and assign it as rootviewcontroller!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your first vc to push (the vc you initial in AppDelegate).
And your first vc must be UINavigationController.
After pushed remember to remove old vc in navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add "#selector()" on your handler.

Comment: what do you mean? That I call the counter functions inside my UIViewControllers?